# Cross-compiling ROS for NAO atom robot

Tags: boost, cross-compiling, nao

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have followed the tutorial: ros.org/wiki/nao/Tutorials/Cross-Compiling_NAO-V4 (could not post as link due to low karma) in order to install ROS on a NAO robot.

My configuration:
Ubuntu 10.04 32-bit,
NAO atom robot,
Aldebaran cross-toolchain: linux32-nao-atom-cross-toolchain-1.14

I did not notice any errors during the tutorial (but I might have missed error messages!), so I transferred the installation to a NAO robot as in step 1.8.
However, when running

> roscore

in a SSH session to the robot, roscore immediately shut down after startup because it could not locate the boost library. It was looking for boost version 1.40, but the files I transferred to the NAO contained boost version 1.48.

Trying to solve my problem I went back to the tutorial and realised I had missed to change

> export ROS_BOOST_VERSION="1.45.0"

to

> export ROS_BOOST_VERSION="1.48"

as 1.48 is the boost shipped with the cross-toolchain tools from Aldebaran.

However, now that I re-do step "1.4 Compiling ROS Base from source" in the tutorial, on

> make -j8

I get a bunch of these errors:

```
    [ 98%] Building CXX object ros_comm/tools/rosbag/CMakeFiles/rosbag.dir/src/buffer.cpp.o
../../../lib/librostime.so: undefined reference to `boost::thread_resource_error::thread_resource_error()'
../../../lib/libroscpp.so: undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::get_current_path_api(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&)'
../../../lib/librostime.so: undefined reference to `boost::lock_error::lock_error()'
../../../lib/libroscpp.so: undefined reference to `boost::system::get_system_category()'
/home/nao/linux32-nao-atom-cross-toolchain-1.14/sysroot/usr/lib/libboost_regex-mt-1_48.so: undefined reference to `std::_List_node_base::_M_transfer(std::_List_node_base*, std::_List_node_base*)@GLIBCXX_3.4.14'
../../../lib/libroscpp.so: undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::create_directory_api(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
../../../lib/libroscpp.so: undefined reference to `boost::system::get_generic_category()'
/home/nao/linux32-nao-atom-cross-toolchain-1.14/sysroot/usr/lib/libboost_regex-mt-1_48.so: undefined reference to `std::_List_node_base::_M_unhook()@GLIBCXX_3.4.14'
/home/nao/linux32-nao-atom-cross-toolchain-1.14/sysroot/usr/lib/libboost_signals-mt-1_48.so: undefined reference to `std::_List_node_base::_M_reverse()@GLIBCXX_3.4.14'
/home/nao/linux32-nao-atom-cross-toolchain-1.14/sysroot/usr/lib/libboost_regex-mt-1_48.so: undefined reference to `std::_List_node_base::_M_hook(std::_List_node_base*)@GLIBCXX_3.4.14'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [ros_comm/tools/rosout/bin/rosout] Error 1
make[1]: *** [ros_comm/tools/rosout/CMakeFiles/rosout.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

Which tells me there's something wrong with boost.
Also, in the step before:

> cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$ROS_FUERTE_DIR

I get these kinds of warnings which might be related:

```
CMake Warning at ros_comm/test/test_roscpp/src/CMakeLists.txt:150 (add_executable):
  Cannot generate a safe runtime search path for target
  test_roscpp-nonconst_subscriptions because files in some directories may
  conflict with libraries in implicit directories:

    runtime library [libgtest.so.0] in /usr/lib may be hidden by files in:
      /home/nao/linux32-nao-atom-cross-toolchain-1.14/sysroot/usr/lib

  Some of these libraries may not be found correctly.
```

There are a lot of these warnings for many different libraries.

I'm a bit lost in all these errors and hope someone can give some insight, thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/53620/cross-compiling-ros-for-nao-atom-robot/) by [I.T](https://answers.ros.org/users/4077/i.t/) on ROS Answers with karma: 67 on 2013-01-29

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I suggest taking your question to the [ROS Embedded SIG](http://www.ros.org/wiki/sig/Embedded)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-03-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0